# TableView Keep Scrolling down with repeated cell items in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

Let's say that I have 10 image items in the tableView, and I implemented a way to make it auto-scroll down every 5 seconds. However, if I'm on the last image, after 5 seconds it will go all the way back to top of the list instead of keep scrolling down with the same animation effect. Is there a way to make it keep going down without going back on top of the list?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is suppose to happen when it gets to the last cell? It can't scroll to a cell that doesn't exist. You could add a tableView footer and scroll to that, but I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sounds like you want an "infinite scrolling carousel" effect - there are some examples of horizontal carousels, so there may be some for vertical as well.

Comment: Thanks @Dominic, infinite scrolling carousel is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could *hack* something like this:

- in `numberOfRowsInSection` put some multiplier of the number of images in your array of images (like 10,000)
- in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` divide `indexPath.row` by the number of images in your array and use the remainder as your array index to pick the image to display.

Of course at some point you will still hit the bottom, but maybe it's enough to avoid it for a very long time (probably longer than the user will sit and watch it!)